# How would a JS module be created?

Tags: javascript, module

I'm a little confused on what to do here. I've seen a lot of people create modules in JS, but everyone usually does it differently. I've seen people wrap their WHOLE module in a `(function(){})();` , or they declare an  object literal, or do something crazy like `window.Module = {};`. I want to know what would be the best choice to be used (as in what you would think is most useful). Help would really be appreciated, and thanks.

Comment: "the best" from what perspective? Nothing is absolutely ideal.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one official solution to create JavaScript modules. Anything else you have seen is either a polyfill for that solution, or a pale echo of the real thing.

The basic syntax is like so:

```
import otherStuff from "otherStuff.js";
var myThing = {};

myThing.stuff = function(){ /*...*/ };
myThing.do = function(){ otherStuff.doOther(); );

export default myThing;
```

It can get much more complicated, but the basics are:

- Your module must be in a unique file. A file is a module.
- Your module should *probably* export something, although this is not strictly necessary.

This is coming down the pipeline in JavaScript. Unfortunately, no one has been able to agree on the official specification of how to **load** the modules, so they are not on a track for any near-future release. That said, the specification is [under development](https://github.com/whatwg/loader/), and a polyfill that implements it [has been created](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader).

Your best bet to use the official module syntax is to run it through [BabelJS](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules) and compile to a shim like [Require](http://requirejs.org/) (which uses the AMD format) so you can use it without the loader specification.

You can read more about the syntax [here](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) and [here](http://jsmodules.io/).

Comment: May you answer me why a lot of people I see answer for ECMAScript6 even if it's not one year old ? Shouldn't we consider a more broad solution ?

Comment: @MasterDJon, the ECMAScript2015 module specification has been finalized for [almost 2 years](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2014-07/jul-30.md) and has been under development for much longer than that. It is a part of the language specification. I'm not sure how much more broad you can get than "use the official language specification that will be implemented in every JS runtime ever." Lack of support now is addressed in my answer via transpilers like Babel.

Comment: @MasterDJon "Shouldn't we consider a more broad solution ?" --- you sure may. One also may address the w3m and lynx as their supported browsers, and other would just use the actual modern standards

Comment: @zerkms & post owner : I understand ! My only point was in backward compatibility which is still needed. Isn't why jQuery was created and librairies alike ? Looking at this [comparison table of support to ES2015](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) tells us that if OP was looking for mobile browser, oups, big problems forsaken. Well, I think you get my point.

Comment: @MasterDJon well, if you target more devices that support a given technology - you use polyfills. That's more beneficial in long term than using ancient solutions just because "a fraction of our customers will never upgrade". "Isn't why jQuery was created and librairies alike ?" --- that's a very reason why you use ES2015 and babel. That's why babel was created.

Answer (score 1):

I would say : It depends on the final usage of your "module". If it's something that will be used internally, which means that no one else outside your business will use it, then anything can be used as long as you all agreed on the proper method. Otherwise, if it would be used by others : less global variables you create, better it is. As example, jQuery use "$" and "jQuery" as global variables (maybe others, but I'm not sure). When people adds modules to it, they always add them to `window.jQuery.[Under jQuery var]` where `[Under jQuery var]` shall be read on jQuery documentation for proper use.